# Fail to add touchmove listener with `Cannot read property 'move' of undefined`

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

Adding `touchmove` listener to an existing element fails in rare cases with an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'move' of undefined
    at zteMove
    at HTMLDivElement.addEventListener
```

User Agent reveals that it happens on ZTE devices on Chrome 45.

Why this error could be happening or what is the way to prevent it?

Comment: I would like to get some help in finding out why this could be happening and what's the way to fix it. If this error happens to me likely it happened to someone else as well.

Comment: Please add your code.